# Creating a hotstring which doesn't replace text

Tags: autohotkey

I have a hotstring in Autohotkey which displays a reminder any time a job code is typed with capital letters.

```
::lpn::
::nast::
::pca::
  if(GetKeyState("Shift")) ; check for capital letters
    MsgBox Reminder - Set direct pay to 100
return
```

Unfortunately, The default behavior of a hotstring is to replace any typed text. This means whenever I type `NAST`, it is replaced with  .

**Can I create a hotstring which doesn't erase the typed job code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This displays a MsgBox any time one of the job codes is typed in upper case. The code is not erased**

```
:*B0C:LPN::
:*B0C:NAST::
:*B0C:PCA::
    MsgBox Reminder - Set direct pay to 100
return
```

**Notes**

- `B0` tells autohotkey not to backspace over the hotstring characters
- `C` tells autohotkey that the hotstring is case sensitive

**Ref**

- [autohotkey documentation for hotstrings](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm)