# Activate hotstring when text is pasted from clipboard

Tags: clipboard, autohotkey

I have an Autohotkey Hotstring which displays a notification any time a job code is typed with capital letters.

```
:*B0C:ASSOC::
:*B0C:COORD::
:*B0C:PRACPHYS::
    MsgBox Reminder - Set indirect pay to 100
return
```

While this works fine when manually typing out a job code, I also want these notifications to display when a job code is copy-pasted from the clipboard.

```
; non-functional pseudo-code
^v:: ; paste
    if (pasted text == ASSOC or COORD or PRACPHYS)
        MsgBox Reminder - Set indirect pay to 100
return
```

**How can I make my script run whenever a matching string is pasted from the clipboard?**

Comment: Related: [Creating a hotstring which doesn't replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45513581/3357935)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This checks the contents of the clipboard when pasting without interfering with the paste operation**

```
~^v::
   if ( clipboard == "ASSOC" || clipboard == "COORD" || clipboard == "PRACPHYS" )
      MsgBox Reminder - Set indirect pay to 100
return
```

**Notes**

- `~` key's native function will not be blocked
- `clipboard` contents of the clipboard in text-only format
- `==` case sensitive string comparison

**Ref**

- [Autohotkey documentation for Hotkeys](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Can this be made to apply when pasting with right-click paste?